# Cannot access SQL Server instance located within the network on another client machine for whom I am a local admin

Tags: sql-server, authentication, networking, remote-access

I have two different computers, and I use both to log into the same domain.
Neither are servers. They are both client computers belonging to the same network.
I am admin on both computers, so I can install \ etc.

On one computer, I install a SQL Server instance `TGLT-LOANER09\SQLEXPRESS01`  (this is what "Serer name" is shown as, when I log in using SQL Server Management Studio).

Next, I want to go over to my other computer, TGLT-73 which has instance SQL Server instance `PCDBI` on it.

But instead of logging into my local instance (`TGLT-73\PCDBI`), I want to log into the instance on my other networked computer.

So I try to log in to `TGLT-LOANER09\SQLEXPRESS01`; but I cannot. I get error as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Error Picture]

I checked the following, and it seems to be configured correctly:

[image: Remoting Configuration]

Comment: Is there some option on my computer to allow other computers to access resources like the SQL Server Instance, or is it supposed to be automatic?

Answer (score 0):

I am dumping the ticket resolution text so that it might help other folks troubleshoot.
The root cause was the bottom 4 steps and link.  My company help desk solved the issue.

- was remotely connected in to tglt-73
- connected in to tglt-loaner09
- trying to connect sql database on tglt-loaner09 to tglt-73
- set the allow remote connections to the database
- set tcp port 1433 set udp port 1434 allowed in firewall inbound rules
- set tcp/ip enabled in sql server manager
- attempted to connect via name
- attempted to connect via ip
- getting error
- able to ping laptop
- allowed network discovery on laptop
- set ipall tcp port to 1433
  with help from jesse discovered the server browser and server agent services were disabled
- enabled these 3 services
- follow the below article to get most of the settings minus the apexsql tools part at the end

https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/